# What are the necessary steps for deploying application on micro-cloud-foundry?

Tags: cloud-foundry

I want to configure  the cloudfoundry environment correctly and test some small application. If any one know, please help me to configure this environment correctly and let me know any use full reference document is available for this, thanks a lot.

I have registered with cloudfoundry and got downloaded following stuffs:
   1) micro-1.2.0.zip
   2) VMware-Player-4.0.2-591240.x86_64.bundle
   3) springsource-tool-suite-2.9.1.RELEASE-e3.7.2-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz

Comment: have you read the tutorial on cloudfoundry.com? http://start.cloudfoundry.com/infrastructure/micro/installing-mcf.html#starting-and-configuring-the-micro-cloud-foundry-virtual-machine

Answer (score 1):

You have everything you need. In short you will need to:

- Install Ruby and then VMC or STS plugin for CF
- Install VMWare player and run the micro instance within it. Basically you will open the *.vmx file in micro through VMWare player. Your machine has to support and enable virtualization for this
- Do necessary configurations and validate your CF with token received online when you created account and domain
- open vmc and change target to point to local CF use command "vmc target CFM_ADDRESS"
- Deploy and test your application

You can follow this tutorial if it helps you: http://cloudspring.com/get-in-the-cloud-with-cloudfoundry/